# Karma - TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined (alternative 'task completion callback called too many times' in runsequence)

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, karma-runner

Running the following gulp task to start a karma server:

```
gulp.task('unit-test', function () {
    // Be sure to return the stream
    return gulp.src(['random text because gulp is weird'])
            .pipe(debug({verbose: true}))
            .pipe(new Server({
                    configFile: __dirname + '/test/unit/karma.conf.js',
                    singleRun: true
                  })
                  .start())
            .on('error', function (err) {
                throw err;
            });
});
```

throws some errors:

```
[17:24:50] 'unit-test' errored after 81 ms
[INFO] [17:24:50] TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
[INFO]     at DestroyableTransform.Readable.pipe (/Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/gulp-debug/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:516:7)
[INFO]     at Gulp.<anonymous> (/Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/gulpfile.js:185:14)
[INFO]     at module.exports (/Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
[INFO]     at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
[INFO]     at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
[INFO]     at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
[INFO]     at runNextSet (/Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/run-sequence/index.js:79:16)
[INFO]     at Gulp.onTaskEnd (/Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/run-sequence/index.js:68:5)
[INFO]     at Gulp.emit (events.js:129:20)
[INFO]     at Gulp.Orchestrator._emitTaskDone (/Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:264:8)
[INFO]     at /Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:275:23
[INFO]     at finish (/Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:21:8)
[INFO]     at cb (/Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:29:3)
[INFO]     at finish (/Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/run-sequence/index.js:53:5)
[INFO]     at runNextSet (/Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/run-sequence/index.js:81:5)
[INFO]     at Gulp.onTaskEnd (/Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/run-sequence/index.js:68:5)
[INFO] [17:24:50] 'clean-build-test' errored after 290 ms
[INFO] [17:24:50] Error: [object Object]
[INFO]     at formatError (/Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:169:10)
[INFO]     at Gulp.<anonymous> (/Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:195:15)
[INFO]     at Gulp.emit (events.js:129:20)
[INFO]     at Gulp.Orchestrator._emitTaskDone (/Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:264:8)
[INFO]     at /Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:275:23
[INFO]     at finish (/Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:21:8)
[INFO]     at cb (/Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:29:3)
[INFO]     at finish (/Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/run-sequence/index.js:53:5)
[INFO]     at Gulp.onError (/Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/run-sequence/index.js:60:4)
[INFO]     at Gulp.emit (events.js:129:20)
[INFO]     at Gulp.Orchestrator._emitTaskDone (/Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:264:8)
[INFO]     at /Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:275:23
[INFO]     at finish (/Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:21:8)
[INFO]     at module.exports (/Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:36:10)
[INFO]     at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
[INFO]     at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
[INFO] [17:24:50] gulp-debug: 0 items
```

Although interestingly the karma tests still pass:

```
...
...
20 07 2015 17:25:34.934:DEBUG [karma]: List of files has changed, trying to execute
20 07 2015 17:25:34.935:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
20 07 2015 17:25:34.937:DEBUG [watcher]: Watching "/Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/webapp/js/lib.js"
20 07 2015 17:25:34.938:DEBUG [watcher]: Watching "/Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/webapp/js/app.js"
20 07 2015 17:25:34.938:DEBUG [watcher]: Watching "/Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/test/unit"
20 07 2015 17:25:34.940:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.2 server started at http://localhost:9876/
20 07 2015 17:25:34.943:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
20 07 2015 17:25:34.944:DEBUG [temp-dir]: Creating temp dir at /var/folders/43/yyskpwq91b3b_qjxpj5nsqkh0000gn/T/karma-97139922
20 07 2015 17:25:34.946:DEBUG [launcher]: /Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs /var/folders/43/yyskpwq91b3b_qjxpj5nsqkh0000gn/T/karma-97139922/capture.js
20 07 2015 17:25:35.982:DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/karma/static/client.html
20 07 2015 17:25:35.991:DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/karma/static/karma.js
20 07 2015 17:25:36.008:DEBUG [karma]: A browser has connected on socket Rwzn4QBMQ6mTGcBFAAAA
20 07 2015 17:25:36.011:DEBUG [web-server]: upgrade /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=Rwzn4QBMQ6mTGcBFAAAA
20 07 2015 17:25:36.028:INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket Rwzn4QBMQ6mTGcBFAAAA with id 97139922
20 07 2015 17:25:36.028:DEBUG [launcher]: PhantomJS (id 97139922) captured in 1.088 secs
20 07 2015 17:25:36.029:DEBUG [karma]: All browsers are ready, executing
20 07 2015 17:25:36.034:DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/karma/static/context.html
20 07 2015 17:25:36.036:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/karma-chai-plugins/node_modules/sinon/pkg/sinon.js
20 07 2015 17:25:36.037:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/karma-chai-plugins/function-bind-polyfill.js
20 07 2015 17:25:36.038:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/webapp/js/lib.js
20 07 2015 17:25:36.048:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/chai/chai.js
20 07 2015 17:25:36.048:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/karma-chai-plugins/chai-adapter.js
20 07 2015 17:25:36.048:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js
20 07 2015 17:25:36.049:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/karma-mocha/lib/adapter.js
20 07 2015 17:25:36.050:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/test/unit/authenticationService.spec.js
20 07 2015 17:25:36.050:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/test/unit/homepage.spec.js
20 07 2015 17:25:36.050:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/chai-as-promised/lib/chai-as-promised.js
20 07 2015 17:25:36.050:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/karma-chai-plugins/node_modules/sinon-chai/lib/sinon-chai.js
20 07 2015 17:25:36.051:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/webapp/js/app.js
....
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 4 of 4 SUCCESS (0.001 secs / 0.003 secs)
```

Attempting to follow the example more closely (adding a callback within the Server call):

```
gulp.task('unit-test', function (cb) {
    // Be sure to return the stream
    return gulp.src(['random text because gulp is weird'])
            .pipe(debug({verbose: true}))
            .pipe(new Server({
                    configFile: __dirname + '/test/unit/karma.conf.js',
                    singleRun: true
                  }, cb)
                  .start())
            .on('error', function (err) {
                throw err;
            });
});
```

leads to errors like:

```
21:48:36] Error: task completion callback called too many times
    at finish (/Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:15:10)
    at cb (/Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:29:3)
    at removeAllListeners (/Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:311:7)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/Users/karianna/Documents/workspace/AdoptOpenJDK_Projects/betterrev_project/betterrev/src/main/angularjsapp/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:322:9)
    at Server.g (events.js:199:16)
    at Server.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at net.js:1419:10
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

Which I think is because I've got nested callbacks (the task is part of a runsequence, i.e.)

```
gulp.task('clean-build-test', function (callback) { 
  runSequence('clean-build', 'unit-test', 'integration-test', callback); 
});
```

I'm very much a noob at Node and Javascript so happy to be told to go away and provide better info :-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, Gulp is only responsible for creating and directing a stream. At the same time, each *middleman*, like your `new Server`-call is responsible for returning a stream from the `pipe` function. Coming from Java, I think that it is the easiest to think in the context of a type system for understanding this. Think of Gulp like a class that implements:

```
interface GulpTask {
  Stream pipe(Stream stream);
}
```

When reaching the function where you call `new Server`, you receive a stream, but you do not return one. As a matter of fact, you do not return anything such that the return value defaults to`undefined`. Thus the error message notifying you that you cannot call `on` on `undefined`. This is as if you implemented:

```
class BrokenStream implements GulpTask {
  @Override
  public Stream pipe(Stream stream) {
    new Server(<something>);
    return null;
  }
}
```

The reason for this happening is that you are using karma directly which does not know about Gulp's streams. Normally, this is not an issue as Karma is used at the end of a pipe.

At the same time, your error handler does not take effect. You need to register error handlers before their potential application, i.e.:

```
gulp.task('unit-test', function () {
  return gulp
    .src(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Xywqv1cDH8'])
    .on('error', function (err) { <do something> }) // Returns a handled stream.
    .pipe(<something>); // The received stream now has an error handler.
});
```

This way, your stream has an error handler attached when being processed by the next pipe instruction. This handler is triggered once any of the following pipe instructions issues an error.

In contrast, the error handler of your code would only be attached in case that no error occurs (given the `new Server` pipe had returned a stream). This is also why your tests are run but you receive the error handler in the end. The error handler is only attached **after** the processing of the previous pipes.

Maybe you are trying to attach an error handler to your Karma server? Then you need to call `on` with different arguments on the newly created server and **not** on the Gulp stream. The [official Karma API](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/dev/public-api.html) tells you how.

As for attaching the callback to the Karma server: I assume that you took this as a starting point: https://github.com/karma-runner/gulp-karma

Note that you are using the Karma server from within a stream. This is not how you normally do it.

Using the pipe, the Karma server is receiving each individual test and triggers a creation for each single one! At the same time, each server instance is receiving the completion callback of the entire task once each individual test has run. Therefore, you recieve the second error message.

You can track this behavior by implementing your own trivial step:

```
var mapStream = require('map-stream');

gulp.task('unit-test', function () {
  return gulp.src(['random text because gulp is weird'])
    .pipe(debug({verbose: true}))
    .pipe(mapStream(function (file, cb) {
      console.log(file);
      return cb(null, file)
    }))
    .pipe(new Server({
      configFile: __dirname + '/test/unit/karma.conf.js',
      singleRun: true
    }).start())
}
```

I am wondering why you are using streams for this purpose at all. Simply define the Karma server as its own tasks as it is done in the example of the former plugin. Alternatively, you need to wrap your server like this:

```
.pipe(mapStream(function (file, cb) {
  new Server({
    configFile: __dirname + '/test/unit/karma.conf.js',
    singleRun: true
  }, cb).start()
 }))
```

This way, the server triggers the file step's callback and not the one of the task and your application also returns a callback that can be tracked by Gulp in order to interoperate with your run sequence.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!  I've moved the error handler as suggested, but as you say since new Server() nor server.start() return a stream, I'm going to get that error regardless. I guess I need to rethink / refactor the whole use of streams since Karma should be used at the end of a pipe. Frustrating since using the gulp-karma plugin made this possible although now it's no longer working due to karma's API change...

Answer (score 0):

```
gulp.task('unit-test', function (cb) {
  new Server({
    configFile: __dirname + '/test/unit/karma.conf.js',
    singleRun: true
  }, cb).start();
});
```

Comment: That unfortunately that results in an unexpected token error.  Pretty sure I've got my brackets right...  Have edited the Q to show indentation a little more clearly.

Comment: Ok, so I looked at it more closely, and you're right. The problem is that new Server() isn't returning a stream. Why are you trying to return a stream? Why not just create a task to run karma? I've modified my answer with a basic task.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it's because the task is part of a runSequence: ```gulp.task('clean-build-test', function (callback) {
    runSequence('clean-build',
            'unit-test',
            'integration-test',
            callback);
});```